# How to unit test a method called by constructor Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I would like to know how to unit test register() method in the below code

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Abc {
    private Xyz xyz;

    @Autowired
    public Abc(Xyz xyz) {

        this.xyz = xyz;
        try {
            register();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unsupported");
        }
    }

    private void doSomething(String ts) {
       //do Something
    }

    private void register() {
        //register something
    }
}
```

How can I unit test this method in a spring boot application. When I try some unit tests the constructor is called even before test method execution

Comment: I'd suggest writing a behavioural test. The call to `register()` should have some expected effect. We can assert that this effect has occured after construction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not test by checking the state of your object created with class Abc ?

This is preferable to checking the calling of private methods as then you can refactor the inner working of the class without having to change the tests, as long as the behaviour and external state is the same.

If you find yourself wanting to check that private methods have been called in a unit test then this is a smell and should rethink your approach I think. Some other questions have already covered similar areas.

If these methods are interacting with some external components then you can mock these components as you normally would with any method and then validate the interaction is as you expect. Whether that interaction happens in one method or another internally should be an implementation detail of the Abc class and externally you shouldn't care.